# PCB header and microcontroller schematics for JTAG connection

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, jtag

I am using f28017f device from Texas Instruments and for my application I have to implement it on PCB. for debugging this device, I need JTAG connection. I will be using xds110 device for debugging. For JTAG connections, I have copied the schematic from device manual. Does this connection seems fine for on-board programming? Which can be seen from below diagram.
[image: JTAG header]

[image: MCU connection]

I have also connected pull down resistor with TRST' pin as suggested by TI. But it means that ground is connected to TRST' pin and TRST will have 1 logic. Will it keep the device to reset mode and device will perform no operation? Is that true? How this situation could be avoided? This scenerio can be seen from below mentioned picture
[image: TRST' connection]

Comment: What is the device manual? And which instrument are you using for programming/debugging? With MSP430 micros, I have used the GANG programmer and the FET tool using an IDC ribbon cable, and my schematics have a different pinout to yours. Can you please post the tools you are using and a link to the device manual you are following? I have looked for the xds110 user guide and can't see a JTAG pinout in it

Comment: Device manual is from f28017 data sheet and page number 25. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms320f28027.pdf?ts=1598272290813&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTMS320F28027

Comment: The "example" circuits in the manuals are good starting places and work for a majority of situations, but just be aware, they are typically geared towards being used in a test environment with the development/evaluation board. Your specific situation may need some tweaks...

Comment: nTRST is there to keep the device *out* of test mode unless it is actively driven high, hence the (required) pull down.